# Regular expression for finding 'href' attribute value of <a> HTML element

Tags: regular-expressions

I need a regex pattern for finding web page links in HTML.

For example

- `<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=elisp+regex+lookaround" ....></a>`

I can use `(?<=href=\").+?(?=\") | (?<=href=\').+?(?=\')` in Python to get the value of href.

But that involves [positive lookbehind assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-22) `(?<=...)` and [positive lookahead assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-20) `(?=...)` which I didn't find in elisp [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html#Regular-Expressions).

Comment: Comparing with your Python approach you would just search for `href=\(["']\)\(.+?\)\1` and use the second group `\2`. But the best way depends on the application. So please give a bit more background to avoid [XY-problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There is no doubt existing Elisp code for various HTML modes. There you will likely already find useful regexps for such things. That could be one place to start. See nxhtml.el, for example. There is also nxml.el.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for your advice, but my intention to give that Python regex is to show I have thought over this problem. I think I have showed my original purpose rather than hide it like what X-Y problems do.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I think the suggestion is that maybe you don’t “need” a regular expression so much as a way to find these values or extract them or move to them. Keep in mind that applying regular expressions to html is I notoriously impossible in general and that there href might in general contain things like no quotes or single quotes or `&apos;` type escape codes. But maybe you really do need one.

Comment: For anyone who is trying to use the regex in the first comment, here is the escaped format when using searches within Emacs and to test the code with re-builder:  `"href=\\([\"']\\)\\(.+?\\)\\1"`